# udev does not run part of script

Tags: udev

I'm trying to make udev disable my laptop keyboard when an external keyboard is connected.  So far I have the following script which works when I call it directly.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=":0"
export XAUTHORITY="/run/user/1002/gdm/Xauthority"
echo $XAUTHORITY >> /home/apockli/list
echo helloX >> /home/apockli/list
echo `which git` >> /home/apockli/list
echo `/usr/bin/git status` >>/home/apockli/list
echo `/usr/bin/xinput list` >> /home/apockli/list
/usr/bin/xinput float `/usr/bin/xinput list | awk '/Apple/' | sed -r 's/.*id=([0-9]+).*/\1/g'`
echo `/usr/bin/xinput list` >> /home/apockli/list
```

When run by actually connecting the keyboard the `list` file contains the following:

```
/run/user/1002/gdm/Xauthority
helloX
/usr/bin/git
*<Some trailing blank lines>*
```

I really don't understand why `which git` works but `/usr/bin/git status` doesn't and the `xinput` commands neither get written to the file or actually end up disabling the keyboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've already spent way too long trying to get this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious why you would want to disable a perfectly good working keyboard?

Comment: Because I use a Planck.  www.olkb.com

Comment: What I meant us my laptop keyboard doesn't generate any errors as it sits there doing nothing all day long. I use a great wireless keyboard and mouse combination. I'm curious why you want to disable the internal.

Comment: Ah, I see. Because I put my keyboard on top of the Mac keyboard and I don't want it pressing the keys.

Comment: LOL now it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It should that way. Udev launches command in other working directory than the one you expect. Check it by adding:

```
pwd >>/home/apockli/list
```

So try by changing home directory:

```
echo `/usr/bin/git -C /home/apockli/ status` >>/home/apockli/list
```

Also, you should have an exiting git repository, to see an output otherwise you get only blank line:

```
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What you see is error message which is from `stderr` stream not `stdout`.